# Sound problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, dell, alsa, soundcard

I bought a new dell laptop and it came pre-install with Ubuntu 14.04. Normally I use OpenSuse. I have problem with sound. It starts pops after boot and it stars crackling play Ubuntu welcome sound, stops for second and it comebacks. After login when I play some sounds it goes away. When I stop playing something the pops and comeback, so when there is silence it pops and starts crackling. I'm listening through my headphones connected to 3.5 jack. I did some research but did not find what probably cause. In my opinion it is wrong set-up of order sound device. Right now it is:

```
    aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and I want to set it up to be `card 0` is `PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]` so it might probably solve but I don't know how to do it in Ubuntu. In OpenSUSE there is yast module to do this.
Please let me know how to do this in Ubuntu 14.04. The output from sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf is

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

My research on this did lead me to other solution but not my problem. Please let my know what else I have to post to compile the whole picture.

Comment: Did you try a newer version of Ubuntu - this helped me with all graphics and sound problems encountered on laptops  so far. The order of the sound cards should not be a problem for the quality of sound playback. If you attach an external device via HDMI you eventually have to reassign the output device (e.g. with pulse audio mixer) as sound playback might be automatically routed to HDMI.

Comment: if you are more familiar with OpenSUSE have you install that OS on this machine to confirm sound is OK thus assuring no hardware issues ... then as other person suggests you should just install a supported Ubuntu release like 18.10 or 18.04  which will have better support from this forum as that release will match their OS ... mastering OS install is key and only achieved by rolling up your sleeves and walking into the unknown

Comment: I faced the same problem on the past. I suggest you upgrade to Ubuntu 18.x.

Answer (score 0):

This question is duplicate - and has already been answered as follows :

You might try to install the music packages rhythmbox and amarok (there are

additional drivers included) with

> sudo apt-get install amarok rhythmbox

if necessary reboot your machine then with

> sudo reboot

(This often worked out as solution, but there is no guarantee for if your machine is
a brandy new one. Hardware should at least be 4 to 8 months old.)